# Custom Round off Logic

Tags: javascript, regex, math, logic, rounding

I want to build a rounding logic that passes the below given test cases :

Result for 0.045 :4

Result for 0.955 :96

Result for 0.995 :100

Result for 0.01 :1

Result for 0.1 :10

Result for 0.175 :18

Result for 0.007 :1

Result for 0.818 :82

Current code:

```js
function roundOff(num) {
  var ld = (num * 1000) % 100

  if (ld >= 50) {
    return (Math.ceil(num * 100));
  } else {
    return (Math.floor(num * 100));
  }
}

document.write("Result for 0.045 :" + roundOff(0.045) + "<br>");
document.write("Result for 0.955 :" + roundOff(0.955) + "<br>");
document.write("Result for 0.995 :" + roundOff(0.995) + "<br>");
document.write("Result for 0.01 :" + roundOff(0.01) + "<br>");
document.write("Result for 0.1 :" + roundOff(0.1) + "<br>");
document.write("Result for 0.175 :" + roundOff(0.175) + "<br>");
document.write("Result for 0.007 :" + roundOff(0.007) + "<br>");
document.write("Result for 0.818 :" + roundOff(0.818) + "<br>");
```

Currently the last two result are not coming up as expected. I know that a different rounding is used in the last two cases ie. 0.007 should return 1 and 0.818 should return 82. Is it possible to write a single logic that covers both ?

Comment: Why 0.045 should return 4 not 5?

Comment: is there a specific reason that you want 0.045 rounded *down* to 4 but all others (0.955, 0.995, 0.175, 0.818 and 0.007) rounded *up*? Trying to discern a logic here, I would have expected that you'd want roundOff(0.045) to return 5.

If the correct return value for 0.045 is 5, then the following forumula should do the trick:

`function roundOff(num) { return Math.round(1000*num/10); }`

If roundOff(0.045) needs to return 4, I don't see an easy way to solve this unless you can specify your requirements with a rule rather than just examples.

Comment: @UrsBeeli The requirement is : Decimal to ##0% number format. If that makes any sense

Comment: I would still expect 0.045 to round up to 5 insteaf of 4 as you specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let num_list = [
    0.045, // 4
    0.955, // 96
    0.995, // 100
    0.01, // 1
    0.1, // 10
    0.175, // 18
    0.007, // 1
    0.818, // 82
];

function roundOff(num) {
    let ld = num * 1000;
    const final = (_ld, _num) => {
        if (_ld >= 50) {
            return (Math.ceil(_num * 100));
        } else {
            return (Math.floor(_num * 100));
        }
    };

    if (ld > 100 || ld < 10) {
        /*
        if the 1st ld is too big or too small, raise the digit forward 1 digi by * 10
        0.818 * 1000 => 818
        (818 > 100) => (818 * 10) % 100 = 80
        (80 >= 50) Math.ceil(0.818 * 100) = 0.82

        0.007 * 1000 => 7
        (7 < 10) => (7 * 10) % 100 = 70
        (70 >= 50) Math.ceil(0.007 * 100) = 1
        */
        ld = (ld * 10) % 100;
        return final(ld, num);
    } else if (ld >= 10) {
        ld = ld % 100;
        return final(ld, num);
    }
}
num_list.forEach(num => console.log(`${num} => ${roundOff(num)}`));
```